# Why does sem_timedwait() not waking up?

Tags: c, time, semaphore, thread-synchronization

I work on an embedded system with eCos:
I have 2 threads within the same process and 1 semaphore.

1. Thread A initializes a semaphore to 0 so that the 1st attempt to take it will block.
2. Thread A sends a command to Thread B, providing a callback.
3. Thread A waits on semaphore with `sem_timedwait`
4. Thread B process the command and increments the semaphore
5. Thread A should be woken up but is still blocked

Here is the code:

**Thread A**

```
static sem_t semaphore;

void callback()
{
    // Do some stuff
    int ret = sem_post(&semaphore);
    // print confirmation message
}

void foo()
{
    int ret = sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);
    if(ret != 0)
    {
        // print errno
    }

    struct timespec ts; 
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts); // Get current date
    ts.tv_sec += 2; // Add 2s for the deadline

    send_command_to_thread_B(&callback);

    ret = sem_timedwait(&semaphore, &ts);
    if(ret != 0)
    {
        // print errno
    }

    // print waking up message
}
```

What is in Thread B is not relevant.

For debug I tried the following:

1. Using `sem_wait` rather than `sem_timedwait` **works**: Thread A is blocked, then unlocked after the callback. But I don't want to use it because if there is a failure in the callback process that prevent the semaphore to be incremented, Thread A will wait forever.
2. If I don't add the 2s to the `timespec` struct, `sem_timedwait` returns immediatly and `errno` is set to `ETIMEDOUT` (seems legit). The callback is called but it is too late for Thread A.
3. I put traces in the callback call to ensure that the semaphore is indeed incremented from 0 to 1: all the process is done, the callback exits but Thread A is still blocked.

Do you guys have any clue ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so actually everything is fine with this code, the issue was elsewhere : I had a re-entrance problem that caused a deadlock.
*Moral*: Carefully protect your resources and addresses in a multi-thread context

Comment: Sir, could you describe your re-entrance problem in detail, please ? I don't understand what possibilities are to cause this issue

Comment: My analysis was flawed. I had a function invoked concurrently, waiting on a lock that was not released. Execution was blocked but not on the semaphore as I thought. In my defense, it was 6 years ago.